# What exactly are the differences between "diligent", "assiduous" and "sedulous"?

Tags: differences, adjectives, connotation

From [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/):

> **[sedulous](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/sedulous)** (formal) showing great care and effort in your work
> synonym: diligent
>
> **[assiduous](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/assiduous)** (formal) working very hard and taking great care that everything is done as well as it can be
> synonym: diligent
>
> **[diligent](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/diligent)** (formal) showing care and effort in your work or duties

These definitions look alike. What they have in common is that these words mean *to take care* and *to put effort into your work*.

All words are formal. None of these seems to be a proper term in a specific field, e.g. medical, law.

I also looked at [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) to get more details. This adds the connotation of *steady* and *earnest* to *diligent* and *unremitting attention* and *persistent application* to *assiduous*. But in the end, these additional information are again describing an equal thing, i.e., continuously doing your work. The entry on *sedulous* doesn't add any more content; it refers to *diligent* and again describes the word with *perseverance*.

From this point (checking dictionaries only), I don't see any difference at all. I continued with a corpora search.

From [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

*Diligent* is most used in combination with *work*, *effort*, *research*, *study* but also *student*, *people*.

> She's a diligent student.
>
> His diligent research identified the value of ...

*Assiduous* is also most used with *work*, *effort*, *research* but not with *student*, *people*. Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary entry on [*assiduous*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/assiduous) lists student as example though.

> He's assiduous in his work.
>
> With assiduous attention to detail ...

*Sedulous* is most used, um, to little results. [BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) has even less content. Merriam-Webster's example is, once again, a student.

So, *diligent* is used most often, followed by *assiduous* and *sedulous* is quite rare.

All words are formal. All words seem to be usable as an attribute to a person (e.g., student) but also specifying the intense care and effort on work, e.g., a research.

I don't see any significant difference in these words, besides frequency. When is a student *diligent*, *assiduous* or *sedulous*? And when is a research *diligent*, *assiduous* or *sedulous*? Or simply: What are the subtle distinctions which aren't represented by dictionaries?

Comment: You might glean something from [English synonymes (sic) explained in alphabetical order](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YEgSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA642&dq=sedulous&hl=en&sa=X&ei=avvQUMrsB8mm0QXQsIHIBQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=sedulous&f=false), but my advice would be to pretend you've never heard of *sedulous* (I hadn't until now, and it's never done me any harm! :) For the other two, use *diligent* when you want to emphasise how *dutifully* someone carries out some precise instructions, and *assiduous* to emphasise how *precisely* someone performs their duties.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no difference in core meaning, and even the connotational penumbrae overlap a lot. It's mostly about the attitude you're trying to convey; and this is going to depend more on each reader's actual experience with the words than with any broad consensus.

Here's how I would use them:

- *Diligent* if I wanted to express respect and admiration for the worker's application to her project
- *Assiduous* if I wanted to express respect for the worker's application and thoroughness, while leaving room to doubt the value of her work
- *Sedulous* if I wanted to acknowledge the worker's application and thoroughness, while leaving room to wonder whether the work might not be better served by insight and imagination

But that's a very personal view; others may feel differently.

Comment: I don't really have an opinion on *sedulous* (apart from the possibility that using it might mark you out as a lexical show-off). But I think my personal opinion on the other two is probably very similar to yours. To me, *diligent* people are usually those who reliably follow instructions to the letter; *assiduous* people are very thorough and exacting, even if they're just doing something of their own choosing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think all three may be used of 'self-starters' - though in that case I suppose one is "instructed" by the needs of the job rather than a supervisor. But as I said, it all depends on who you've been listening to and reading. They're very close.

Comment: I like that - as per usual - you make your key point straight away *(no difference in core meaning)*. I assumed that by *leaving room to doubt the value...* you were implying that an *assiduous* person might just devote meticulously thorough attention to detail in *anything* they happen to be doing (not necessarily even "goal-oriented" from others' point of view). Whereas *express respect and admiration* implies the *diligent* person does *exactly and thoroughly whatever they're **supposed** to do* (i.e. *some assigned task, their job/duty*).

Comment: I agree that to me "diligent" has connotations of following instructions exactly, carrying out assigned duties to the fullest, or meeting every specified requirement (see: "due diligence"). Whereas "assiduous" on the other hand doesn't have those connotations, even though it has the same meaning. And I've never even heard the word "sedulous" before.

Answer (score 6):

Of the three synonyms, *diligent* is by far the most commonly used, in my experience. And *sedulous* is the least common — you'll get a lot of strange looks if you use it.

I use and hear *diligent* much more often than *assiduous*.

*Assiduous* is more about attentiveness/attention/attendance, and *diligence* is more about effort.

- [*assiduous*](http://www.wordswarm.net/dictionary/assiduous.html)
- [*diligent*](http://www.wordswarm.net/dictionary/diligent.html)

Answer (score 1):

Assiduous allows for improvement to rules rather than the 'blind' following that is diligence. It is more than diligence.

Comment: Do you have any evidence or citations to back this up?

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. I think of *diligent* as more formulaic than *assiduous*; that is to say, a diligent person follows instructions to the letter, while an assiduous person puts great energy and effort into everything she does. I recently used "assiduity" over "diligence" in a letter of recommendation because I wanted to emphasize the student's earnest and unremitting application, as opposed to just an ability to sit there and finish his work. To me personally, *assiduous* is the word that leaves less room to doubt the value of the work, while *diligent* seems more mechanical.

My mental analogy is as follows:

*Assiduous* : Practicing writing skills :: *Diligent* : Reciting times tables

Answer (score 0):

“Elinor wanted very much to know, though she did not chuse to ask, whether Edward was then in town; but nothing would have induced Fanny voluntarily to mention his name before her, till able to tell her that his marriage with Miss Morton was resolved on, or till her husband’s expectations on Colonel Brandon were answered; because she believed them still so very much attached to each other, that they could not be too sedulously divided in word and deed on every occasion.”

- Jane Austen, Sense and Sensibility

Here again, it’s used as an adverb to describe a carefully and regularly repeated action.

The word root comes from the old French for “zealous,” which makes sense.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer, just an example.

> She slaved, toiled, patched and mended, sang and played backgammon, read out the newspaper, cooked dishes for old Sedley, walked him out **sedulously** into Kensington Gardens or the Brompton lanes, listened to his stories with untiring smiles and affectionate hypocrisy, or sat musing by his side and communing with her own thoughts and reminiscences, as the old man, feeble and querulous, sunned himself on the garden benches and prattled about his wrongs or his sorrows.
>
> <sub>(from *Vanity Fair* by W. M. Thackeray; describing Amelia's life devoted to comforting her widowed father.)</sub>

I hadn't seen the word *sedulous* or *sedulously* before, but I thought it probably meant the same as assiduously before looking up the word.

Answer (score -4):

Sedulous sounds like studious. I use sedulous in regards to people who live a lifestyle that in the real world is in alignment with being like a professional athlete. A Mike Jordan if you will.

Jordan practices basketball diligently as well as goes over the pre and post game tapes with assiduous detail, but over all as a person who not only watches what he eats but pain stakenly rises early, is never poorly dressed and has millions of products solid to his name, all we can say is that he is a sedulous being of profound wisdom and vigor.

PS. Diligent is over used and I found sedulous by seeking the hard to find antomyms for indolent, yet my seaking was diligent and attention to detail assiduous.

Pps. Using vocabulary to mind manipulate others into feeling less than is not my goal by avoiding the  diligent word, rather seeking fresh ways to edify powerful people taking rare actions of transformative quality.