# Respectful Noun for Really Hard Worker

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, compliment

I'm reading Jon Gertner's *The Idea Factory: Bell Labs and the Great Age of American Innovation*. 
In describing the history of the telephone, Gertner describes Thomas Edison (whose inventions helped improve transmitting voices) with:

> Edison usually worked eighteen hours a day or longer, pushing for weeks on end, ignoring 
>   family obligations, taking meals at his desk, refusing to pause for sleep or showers.

This perseverance reminded me of a personality in David Kushner's history of software company *id* in *Masters of Doom*. 
It cites game engine designer [John Carmack](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_D._Carmack) 
as saying:

> If you want to set off and go develop some grand new thing, you don't need millions of 
>   dollars of capitalization. You need enough pizza and Diet Coke to stick in your 
>   refrigerator, a cheap PC to work on, and the dedication to go through with it. We slept on 
>   floors. We waded across rivers.

I recall the book also having an anecdote where Carmack's co-workers test his resolve.
They play a movie at high volume while Carmack is working.
After turning around briefly to see what's going on, Carmack continues his work as before.
And throughout the book Carmack puts that kind of effort into every project he attempts.

I would like a noun that captures more intensity than *hard worker*.
There are *hard workers* and then there are very devoted workers, who may agree with 
[Gustave Flaubert](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Gustave_Flaubert)'s quote:

> *L'homme n'est rien, l'oeuvre – tout* [which translates to] The man is nothing, the work - all

At the same time I would like the noun to be respectful, if not praise the subject for their industry.
For this reason I'd like to avoid *workaholic*, which has a compulsory and involuntary aspect to it, as shown in this [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/balance/features/are-you-a-workaholic) quote from *Are You a Workaholic?*:

> But for workaholics, the day of rest never comes. There is always one more email to read, 
>   one more phone call to take, one more critically important trip to the office that can't 
>   wait until Monday.
>
> Weekends? Holidays? Family? As the uber-workaholic Ebenezer Scrooge put it, "Bah, humbug!"

Similarly, [*busy bee*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/busy-bee) is not serious enough for my situation.

The word I like most so far is *workhorse*, defined by [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workhorse) to be:

> a dependable person who does a lot of work

Unfortunately I am drawn to think of being overworked to the point of injury, such as [Black Beauty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Beauty#Part_4), who "collapses from overwork," or Boxer in [Animal Farm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Farm#Plot_summary), who "[despite] his injuries... continues working harder and harder, until he collapses while working on the windmill."

Is there a complimentary, respectful, or more neutral noun to describe a really hard worker?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered in the [What exactly are the differences between “diligent”, “assiduous” and “sedulous”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94744/what-exactly-are-the-differences-between-diligent-assiduous-and-sedulous) thread.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Those are adjectives. I'm looking for a noun or noun-phrase, like *workaholic*, *busy bee*, or *workhorse*.

Comment: FWIW, googling for *slacker antonym* just pointed to *hard worker*. You might find a single word that means specifically what you are asking (a respectful term for a very hard worker), but you might not.

Comment: This is perhaps not very common, but I've heard "He is _a force of nature_" as a compliment. It is generally said in awe at the subject's prodigious skills or output. More colloquially, one may refer to such a coworker as (a) _beast_ (works as both noun and adjective).

Comment: You could also describe Edison and Carmack as being overly obsessed about their work, which they clearly enjoy. I think that someone who has to hold down two jobs for financial reasons is a harder worker.

Comment: I find it a little telling that there's no true single word for the opposite of a workaholic. Could it be that in the English-speaking culture, someone who works too hard is just suspect? To my knowledge at least 'workaphiliac' is not an official word.

Comment: Dynamo, machine, or workhorse are generally respectful (in that they are at least not disrespectful), informal terms for someone who works very hard/very quickly.

Comment: Despite what you say, I suspect that "workaholic" is the best term.

Comment: @AndyBlankertz Good point. My examples are stilted toward those who are passionate about what they do. But my core question (put one way "What's a noun for someone who works harder than most?") seeks to find a word for the workers you describe too. In my book, someone who does not let little things distract them from their job is a hard worker. Someone who does that all day, while holding more than one job? They're very hard workers! And another who does that and then goes home to work on a hobby or pet project instead of relaxing? Phenomenal! What do you call someone like that?

Comment: Someone like that? He must be obsessed, single-minded, driven or divorced. All adjectives I'm afraid.

Comment: Or coin a new word, like "nerdoholic". I think it fits, but unfortunately only nerdoholics would understand what it means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A person who works extremely hard in every way can be called a **Trojan**:

> **Trojan 1**  n.
>
> 2. A person of courageous determination or energy.  [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Trojan)
>
> **Trojan** n
>
> 2. a person who is hard-working and determined  [Collins]

The metaphor seems to be derived from the phrase 'worked like a Trojan'. From [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/7/messages/801.html):

> WORK LIKE A TROJAN -
>
> "Trojan originally referred to the inhabitants of
>   Troy, the ancient city besieged by the Greeks in their efforts to
>   retrieve their queen, Helen, who had been abducted by the son of the
>   King of Troy. According to legend, as recorded in both Vergil's
>   'Aeneid' and Homer's 'Illiad,' the Trojans were a hard-working,
>   determined, industrious people. Hence: 'He worked like a Trojan.' "
>   From "Morris Dictionary of Word and Phrase Origins" by William and
>   Mary Morris....

In a far less formal register, in Britain the term **grafter** is almost always taken as a real compliment; both the following definitions from [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grafter):

> *grafter* noun
>
> (British, informal) a hard worker [: *Fred's a real grafter*]

but not in the US:

> *grafter* noun
>
> (informal) a person who acquires money, power, etc, by dishonest or
>   unfair means, esp by taking advantage of a position of trust

Comment: Considering *Trojan* is often associated with infiltration and malicious intent (thanks to the *Trojan Horse* and, more recently, *trojan viruses*), I suspect use of this term even with the intent of respect would be met with confusion and require clarification to avoid offense.

Comment: If the person's as good as OP says, I doubt this.

Comment: I like the direction this is headed. (If I were asked "Like the Trojan horse?" I would remind the asker that the horse was not from the Trojans but from their enemies the Greeks, hence [*Beware of Greeks bearing gifts*](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beware-of-greeks-bearing-gifts.html).) I'm interested in finding out more, especially what in particular the Trojans did to earn such an honor. I think this is what I'm looking for; I'll accept tomorrow!

Answer (score 10):

Someone who is more than just a hard worker can be described as [*persevering*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/persevering):

> To persist in or remain constant to a purpose, idea, or task in the face of obstacles or discouragement. *The three great essentials to achieve anything worthwhile are, first, hard work; second, stick-to-itiveness; third, common sense.* ― Thomas A. Edison *I do not think that there is any other quality so essential to success of any kind as the quality of perseverance. It overcomes almost everything, even nature.* - John D. Rockefeller

[*passionate*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/passionate):

> having, compelled by, or ruled by intense emotion or strong feeling; fervid; zealous. *I have no special talents. I am passionately curious.* -Albert Einstein (1879 - 1955) *When natural inclination develops into a passionate desire, one advances towards his goal in seven-league boots.* - Nikola Tesla *I think I overcame every single one of my personal shortcomings by the sheer passion I brought to my work. I don’t know if you’re born with this kind of passion, or if you can learn it. But I do know you need it.* - Sam Walton

[*disciplined*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dedicated):

> Controlled behavior resulting from disciplinary training; self-control. *Does thou love life? Then do not squander time; for that’s the stuff life is made of.* - Ben Franklin *Things may come to those who wait, but only the things left by those who hustle.* - Abraham Lincoln (1809-1865) *In reading the lives of great men, I found that the first victory they won was over themselves… self-discipline with all of them came first.* - Harry S. Truman (1884-1972)

[*dedicated*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dedicated):

> Wholly committed to a particular course of thought or action; *devoted*. *It is rather for us here dedicated to the great task remaining before us, that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion.* - Abraham Lincoln (1809-1865)

[*zealous*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/zealous):

> Filled with or motivated by zeal; fervent. *Allowing only ordinary ability and opportunity, we may explain success mainly by one word and that word is WORK! WORK!! WORK!!! WORK!!!!* - Frederick Douglass (1818-1895)

[*ardent*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ardent): Displaying or characterized by strong enthusiasm or devotion; fervent.

syn: perseverance, persistence, tenacity imply determined continuance in a state or in a course of action. *perseverance* suggests effort maintained in spite of difficulties or long-continued application; *it is used in a favorable sense*: The scientist's perseverance finally paid off in a coveted prize. persistence, which may be used in a favorable or unfavorable sense, implies steadfast, unremitting continuance in spite of opposition or protest: an annoying persistence in a belief. tenacity is a dogged and determined holding on: the stubborn tenacity of a salesman. (TFD)

Comment: Dayum! You wanted a noun? Sorry. :(

Comment: "Disciple" works as a noun. It carries a heavy religious connotation that is likely to emphasize the point without being taken literally as pertaining to religion.

Comment: @TecBrat A disciple is a follower of someone, it doesn't refer to someone having discipline in a field.

Comment: @Barmar I know the literal meaning, but if you use it in context, I'm sure it will make the point, similar to "Zealot" mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: I guess I'd have to see the context to judge. But I think I would find it confusing -- "disciple of who?"

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps *diligent*:

> [*diligent*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diligent)
>
> 1. constant in effort to accomplish something; attentive and persistent in doing anything.
> 2. done or pursued with persevering attention; painstaking.
>
> *Dictionary.com*

Edit: In light of the updated question, some more options include *achiever*:

> [*achiever*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/achiever) (one who achieves), i.e.
>
> 1. to bring to a successful end; carry through; accomplish
> 2. to get or attain by effort; gain; obtain
>
> *Dictionary.com*

Or *man of action*:

> [*man of action*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/man+of+action):
>
> 1. A person who prefers to act rather than contemplate and gets things accomplished quickly an efficiently.
>
> *TheFreeDictionary.com*

The latter does have connotations of the "shoot first, ask questions later" type, however.

'Nother edit: thanks to medica's suggestion, I found a definition for *high achiever*:

> [*high achiever*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/business-english/high-achiever):
>
> 1. a person who achieves more than the average person in their work
>
> *Cambridge Business English Dictionary - Cambridge Dictionaries Online*

Comment: +1, *diligent* is a good word, but I'm looking for a label or noun. I've edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: +1 - for *achiever*... but above that is *high achiever* (no help there) then *over-achiever* (negative).

Comment: Please note that where you quote from someone else's work, you must cite the source in plain text [a link is not enough] and use `>` quoting to indicate its extent. [SE policy](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 7):

A **trooper** would fit. A trooper is a soldier, but the term is often used colloquially to mean someone who works hard, or is persevering.

> Jane is a real *trooper* she stayed in all weekend to get the report done by monday.

Also a **team-player**. A team-player is someone who works for the good of the team.

> Jim is a great *team-player*, he changed his lunch plans so he could help out at a critical meeting we had.

Answer (score 7):

**Workhorse** could fit.  It's not necessarily positive, but it isn't negative either.

Comment: This was the only noun I could think of that really matched, and I think you nailed its tone: neutral. In the right context, it can definitely be positive.

Comment: It could imply someone with little skill, but lots of determination, but that's not necessarily bad.

Answer (score 6):

You asked for a *noun* but oddly, most of the answers above seem to be adjectives. May I suggest a **stalwart**. This is positive, despite appearances, and seems to have pretty universally gone from meaning strong, courageous, and persevering to meaning someone who is the backbone of some operation.

Comment: It is not work-related. It does not describe a hard **worker**.

Comment: It certainly can describe a hard worker. In fact, I think it's most often used for that purpose. See these links for example, which describe retiring professors, caretakers and mechanics. http://www.sun.ac.za/english/Lists/news/DispForm.aspx?ID=1391 http://www.wnsc.ac.uk/2014/09/college-stalwart-retires-after-24-years/ http://www.vertumotors.com/news/bristol-street-motors-stalwart-retires-after-50-years-in-the-motor-trade--BB356/#.VDSBdOf6s5I

Comment: Of course it **can** describe a hard worker if you say that the person is a stalwart at work or at working. And that is how those articles use it. *Stalwart* means strong, dependable, or loyal. Nothing in the definition of *stalwart* implies that the stalwart is a strong, dependable, or loyal **worker**.

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: I've never seen stalwart used as a noun. (Just commenting on that fact)

Answer (score 5):

A hard worker might be described as a *[Stakhanovite](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stakhanovite)*:-

> an efficient worker, esp in the former Soviet Union, who may be
>   offered incentives [Collins English Dictionary]

or

> a worker in the Soviet Union who regularly surpassed production quotas
>   and was specially honored and rewarded. [Random House Dictionary via Dictionary.com]

Comment: Also Boxer the Horse in Animal Farm...

Comment: The original Stakhanov was, I believe, glorified under Stalin as a _model worker_. The great early 1980s band Magazine (headed by Howard Devoto, previously of Buzzcocks) has a sarcastic aspirational song called "[Model Worker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wB7VOHRrSoE)."

Comment: This word might be considered offensive in Eastern Europe.

Answer (score 4):

I've described such people before as *machines*.

> *noun*
>   **1.** an apparatus consisting of interrelated parts with separate functions, used in the performance of some kind of work.

<sup>Source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/machine)</sup>

It's a bit slang in this context, and can be taken to be derogatory for it's dehumanizing connotation. However, I've only personally used it and heard it used in admiration, as in someone who can work hard for long hours without rest or breaks typically afforded to the human workforce.

> Joe just pulled his third all-nighter this week. The guy is a machine.

Expanding on that theme, similar terms with the same connotation are (also from Dictionary.com):

> *[android](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/android)* 
>   noun
>   **1.** an automaton in the form of a human being.

and

> [*cyborg*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cyborg) 
>   noun
>   **1.** a person whose physiological functioning is aided by or dependent upon a mechanical or electronic device.

That doesn't capture the flavor very closely. The exact usage has a closer connotation to

> [*bionic*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bionic)
>   adjective
>   **2.** *Informal.* having superhuman strength or capacity.

Answer (score 3):

An innocuous and an informal noun would be ***eager beaver***.

> - one that is exceptionally, often excessively industrious or zealous
> - a person who displays conspicuous diligence, esp one who volunteers for extra work
>
> <sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eager-beaver</sup>

You can consider ***go-getter*** also.

> a person who works very hard and who wants very much to succeed
>
> <sup>http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-getter</sup>

Answer (score 1):

*Workaholic* might fit, but that really means someone who works a lot, not necessarily someone who works hard or well.  It suggests a compulsion to work.

Comment: The question specifically says the OP would like to avoid the term workaholic.

Answer (score 1):

To capture the person's drive and determination, **Workhorse** (or **warhorse**) seem the best among the possibilities thrown up, but **trooper** or **dynamo** are pretty good too (and **yeoman** might do, but yeoing is an archaic and forgotten line of work). Related to trooper, you could also use **soldier**, indeed its gerund seems almost perfect for the context: **soldiering** on.

See what Jagger-Richards say about "the common footsoldier" in "Salt of the Earth"

Answer (score 0):

While not a noun, there is the phrase *[on a mission](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/on+a+mission.html)* that describes the qualities of the actor

> Being on a mission refers to acting in a determined way and so focus in doing something that he/she is oblivious of anything else around him/her

[*usingenglish.com*]

The expression *He is a man on a mission* is used to describe someone who is driven to complete his objective. The phrease has a neutral to positive tone.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/yeoman

The definition includes the idiomatic use:

yeoman's work:

> very good, hard, and valuable work that someone does especially to support a cause, to help a team, etc.

Which, I realize, is not strictly a synonym for the doer of the the work, but which is unequivocally flattering.

Answer (score 0):

Just skimming all of these it sounds like dynamo fits all the requirements and doesn't violate the anti-requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**Diligence (n.)**
mid-14c., from Old French diligence "attention, care; haste, speed," from Latin diligentia "attentiveness, carefulness," from diligentem (nominative diligens) "attentive, assiduous, careful," originally present participle of diligere "single out, value highly, esteem, prize, love; aspire to, be content with, appreciate," originally "to pick out, select," from dis- "apart" (see dis-) + legere "choose, gather" (see lecture (n.)).

Sense evolved from "love" through "attentiveness" to "carefulness" to "steady effort." From the secondary French sense comes the old useage of diligence for "public stage coach" (1742; dilly for short), from a French shortening of carrosse de diligence.

**Grinder (n.)**
the meaning "hard-working student" is American English slang from 1864. The sense "steady, hard work" first recorded 1851 in college student slang.

**Student/Studious (n.)** 14c. (implied in studiously) "zealous, diligent, eager," from Latin studiosus "devoted to study, assiduous, zealous," from studium "eagerness, zeal" (see study). From late 14c. as "eager to learn, devoted to learning," also, as noun, "those who study or read diligently." Related: Studiousness.

http://etymonline.com/

Comment: all definitions are from etymonline.com

Comment: You should edit your answer to put the citation in it.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamo, fireball, firebrand, go-getter

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be improved by providing examples and/or more detailed explanation, including links to dictionaries and other relevant references. The [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will provide additional guidance.

Answer (score -1):

Does **salaryman** describe it?

A few snippets from the [Wikipedia definition:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salaryman)

> ... has gradually become accepted in English-speaking countries as a noun for a Japanese white-collar businessman... In modern use, the term carries associations of long working hours... The following are stereotypical images of the salaryman:
>
> - Lifestyle revolves entirely around work at the office.
> - Works over-time on a daily basis.
> - Diligent but unoriginal.
> - Thoroughly obedient to orders from the higher levels of the company.

There are other parts of the definition that don't conform to, and in some cases even conflict with, the description in your question (for example, karoshi - death from overwork) but depending on the context, **salaryman** might possibly convey the meaning you intend.

Comment: Those first two bulletpoints are excellent. The third is not what I intend. I regard Edison and Carmack as very original. But +1, since I've seen several definitions for *salaryman* containing "long hours". The time spent working is an important factor of what I'm looking for.

Comment: So you are looking only for a white-collar or salaried worker? Say so in your question, if so. If not, the answer does not fit workers in general.

Comment: Isn't it a bit harsh to downvote an answer because of a shortcoming in the question? I pointed out the ways in which salaryman might and might not fit the definition, and also mentioned that it depended on the context.

Answer (score -1):

One of your examples describes a hard-worker in a software development setting. This is creative work, and often working *hard* is not the goal. In a more creative work setting a prodigious coder is great because she can solve hard problems quickly. In that context **sui generis** can fit well. From [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sui%20generis):

> constituting a class alone

In other words, this person is so damn good that he is head an shoulders above his peers.

While Webster gives the definition of sui generis as an adjective, [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/English_in_Use/Nouns#Sui_generis) describes the phrase as an abstract noun.

Answer (score -3):

> jug·ger·naut
>   ˈjəɡərˌnôt/
>   noun
>   noun: juggernaut; plural noun: juggernauts
>
> > a huge, powerful, and overwhelming force or institution.
> >         "a juggernaut of secular and commercial culture"

> tour de force
>   ˌto͝or də ˈfôrs/
>   noun
>   noun: tour de force; plural noun: tours de force
>
> > an impressive performance or achievement that has been accomplished or managed with great skill.
> >         "his novel is a tour de force"
> >         synonyms:   triumph, masterpiece, achievement, success, masterful performance, magnum opus

[[From Google definition]](https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=_Wk0VJzgDsGxyATZyYKwDg&ved=0CAcQ1S4#q=tour+de+force)

Comment: Not work-related.

Comment: [Do *not* copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)