# How can the phrase "a tireless workaholic" be defined?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I want to heap praise on a person. He is a very hard-worker and works most of the time of a day. He takes a great workload and is always eager to take further workload. His tasks are quantitatively and qualitatively appreciable. He never complains and keeps on discharging the jobs with a smile. I want to devise a catchline, much like what most of the advertisements today use, for him. The catchline I devised is "... a tireless workaholic". (I know that "workaholic" has a negative shade and is used mainly for those who keep so engrossed in work that they have no time for the other aspects of life. But, I find no better word either. So, I have settled for "workaholic". Now, I want to change the shade of the word by qualifying the word with a positive adjective. I find no better adjective than "tireless".) First, I do not know if the catchline is grammatically correct. If correct, I do not know if, for "tireless", a better adjective could be substituted. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Respectful Noun for Really Hard Worker](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200340/respectful-noun-for-really-hard-worker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use **inexhaustible** that is a synonym of tireless, untiring, never wearying.

> Example: William Thompson was an *inexhaustible* worker, producing
>   almost six hundred papers, seventy patents, as well as a number of
>   books during his tenure.

Answer (score 2):

You might say "energetic, selfless team player". It implies that he works hard and puts job and co-workers before himself, without the same negative connotation as "workaholic".

Comment: Sir, I want a catchline. A catchline could not perhaps be so long. It would be very helpful if you could improve the catchline I have devised "... a tireless workaholic" or you could suggest a better catchline or a one-word substitution or a line consisting of four-five words.

Comment: I like @Misneac's suggestion. Building on that, how about "driven and relentless?"

Comment: @ Dinesh Kumar Garg 'energetic, selfless team player' **has** four words. If you want to be picky (I'd personally like Misneac's accolade a lot), your question is inappropriate for the site as selecting 'primarily opinion-based answers'. 'Workaholic' is _not_ a compliment.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,

"he's a [***real eager beaver***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=real+eager+beaver&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creal%20eager%20beaver%3B%2Cc0)."

> [eager beaver](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x336dm7): an exceptionally zealous person, one who habitually takes on more tasks or works harder than others. For example, *Bill is a real eager beaver, always volunteering to stay late*. This expression became especially popular during World War II, applied to recruits anxious to impress their commanding officers by such behavior. [First half of 1900s]
>   [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/eager+beaver)

"he's a ***real ball of fire (or fireball)*** on the job."

> ball of fire: a highly energetic and indefatigable person; also ***human dynamo***, ***powerhouse***, ***live wire***, [***busy bee***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/busy+bee) [WordNet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ball+of+fire)

Answer (score 0):

"Workaholic" is indeed not the best word because of it's negative connotations of compulsiveness and lack of time to do anything besides work.

I would use words like **"dedicated"**, **"committed"**, or **"hard worker"** to describe that person:

> committed: willing to **work very hard** at something SYN **dedicated**

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/committed))

Consider:

> He is **extremely committed**.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using "[***respectable***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/respectable)" before "workaholic", which means:

> Regarded by society to be good, proper, or correct

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

> (1) Worthy of respect: estimable, (2) Decent or correct in character or behavior.

[[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/respectable)]

The word "workaholic" itself has a connotation of being too much focused on work without taking care of other things such as family issues and its meaning is *negative*. By putting those adjectives like "respectable" or "estimable", you could achieve what you want.

I don't think adding "tireless" before it reduces the negative connotation and it might work in the opposite way.